# react-native-pdf iOS and Android build errors

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-pdf

Tried to create build in iOS and Android. App is using react-native-pdf library. Getting build errors

Error: Unable to resolve module react-native-blob-util from
/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-pdf/index.js: react-native-blob-util could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules
../../node_modules

We tried adding react-native-blob-util to package.json. But now getting duplicate symbols build error in iOS, because of react-native-blob-util

"react-native-blob-util": "^0.13.16",
"react-native-pdf": "^6.4.0"

Comment: Could you post a screenshot from your `package.json`

Comment: I used `"react-native": "0.64.0", "react-native-pdf": "^6.3.0", "react-native-blob-util": "^0.13.17"`. It's working without error.

Answer (score 7):

i get this case too and the best way is

1. uninstall react-native-blob-util and react-native-pdf

```
npm uninstall react-native-blob-util
npm uninstall react-native-pdf
```

2. install react-native-pdf version  to 6.2.0

`npm install react-native-pdf@6.2.0`

3. install rn-fetch-blob, or if you already have

`npm i rn-fetch-blob`

4. `npm install`